# Transformer - If the Output V number matches, does it matter that the A numbers are different"

Tags: transformer, output

The transformer that came with my Kinkle Fire say "DC Output: 5V[image]1.8A".  I want to install some [Fastmac Usockets](http://fastmac.com/usocket.php) in my house but their specs say "Output: 5VDC 2.4A".  **Do the different A numbers matter?**  I don't want to damage the Fire.

Comment: Before asking, you should at least know what's an Ampère :)

Comment: @clabacchio, An extremely emotional Mathematician?

Answer (score 10):

"A numbers" and "V numbers" refer to the Ampere and Volt capacity of the unit, respectively.  Also, you don't have a "transformer".  What you have is a "power supply".  Transformers only put out AC, which is inherent to how they work.  The solid line above the dashed line is a symbol indicating DC, as apposed to AC.

So, your equipment came with a 5 Volt 1.8 Amp power supply, and you want to know whether you can replace the power supply with one rated for 5 Volts and 2.4 Amps.  Yes, you can.  The Volt ratings must match, but a higher Amp rating is OK.  This only indicates how much current the power supply is capable of delivering *if the load demands it*, not how much it will deliver.  Since 1.8 A is apparently sufficient for your device, the extra .6 A capacity of the new power supply won't be used but will do no harm.

This concept is like the limit on a credit card.  A $2,400 limit will still work even if you will only ever borrow $1,800.

Comment: Finally: An analogy that makes sense to the average consumer!

Comment: ... except that cheap power supplies may only be at the specified voltage when also at the listed amperage. A significantly lighter load may result in a higher output voltage. You need to test the supply voltage to make sure it's actually regulated (or at least outputs what voltage you want at the load you want)

Comment: Olin,  What a great answer !!!  Thank you.  Not only did you answer my question but educated me in the process.  I (and other members of my household) will not confused transformers and power supplies again.  I had tried to find the answer for myself on Wiki and Answers and elsewhere but nothing was a clear and concise as your answer.  Again, thank you.